# Set Google Analytics default date range from XX date to CURRENT?

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

Is it possible to set Google Analytics default date range from XX date to CURRENT? For example, January 1, 2017 to Today (dynamic).

Answer (score 0):

The [Google analytics core reporting API v3](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#startDate) has this option

> Values must match [0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}|today|yesterday|[0-9]+(daysAgo).

Unfortunately the [Google Analytics Reporting API v4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#daterange) does not.

> DateRange A contiguous set of days: startDate, startDate + 1 day, ..., endDate. The start and end dates are specified in ISO8601 date format YYYY-MM-DD.

```
{
  "startDate": string,
  "endDate": string,
}
```

It must be a date, you will need to calculate today from within your application before sending the request to Google.

This is an interesting idea I think you should log it as a feature request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187400). If you do link it here and I will star it with you and bring it up with the team the next time I speak to them.

Comment: I pinged one of devs see if it's something on the list or not. I will let you know if I hear back.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you.

Comment: @DaImTo V4 does support XdaysAgo, yesterday and today. [see this example](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/analytics%20reporting/analyticsreporting/v4/analyticsreporting.reports.batchGet?_h=2&resource=%257B%250A++%2522reportRequests%2522%253A+%250A++%255B%250A++++%257B%250A++++++%2522dateRanges%2522%253A+%250A++++++%255B%250A++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++%2522startDate%2522%253A+%25227daysAgo%2522%252C%250A++++++++++%2522endDate%2522%253A+%2522today%2522%250A++++++++%257D%250A++++++%255D%252C%250A++++++%2522viewId%2522%253A+%25221174%2522%250A++++%257D%250A++%255D%250A%257D&)

Comment: @matt fix the documentation then it says it doesn't